# Decompose and compute the sign of $\sigma(k)=n+1-k$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations

Let $n\geq 2$ and $\sigma$ is permutationof $\{1,2,\ldots,n  \}$ defined by :

$$\sigma(k)=n+1-k$$

- Decompose permutation $\sigma$ into product of disjoint transpositions  and compute the sign of it ?

indeed,

Here is solution from book but i can't understand it would someone elaborate it  please

$$\forall k\in \{1,2,\ldots,n \}\ \sigma(k)=n+1-k \mbox{ and } \sigma(n+1-k)=k$$

So there are two cases according to the parity of n.

- If $n$ is even: $n=2m$, where $m \in \mathbb{N}^*$. Then

$$\prod_{k=1}^m\left(k,2m+1-k \right) \mbox{ and } \operatorname{sign}(\sigma)=(-1)^{m}  $$

If $n$ is an odd number, $n=2m+1$ with $m\in \mathbb{N}^*$. So

$$\prod_{k=1}^m\left(k,2m+2-k \right) \mbox{ and } \operatorname{sign}(\sigma)=(-1)^{m}  $$

Comment: It looks like it reflects $k$ through the middle element in the set. Can you write a permutation like this $\sigma = (1~2~3~...n)^{n-1}$? I think that will flip every element in the set $n$

Comment: oh I guess it's asking you to write $\sigma$ as a product of disjoint transpositions. Hm, that seems tedious though. $\sigma = (1~~~n)(2~~~n-2)(3~~~n-3)...(k~~~n+1-k) $etc

Comment: yes disjoint transpositions

Answer (score 0):

let    $n=2m $ or $n=2m+1$ according to $n$ even or odd,
let $\gamma = \Pi_{1\leq i\leq m} \tau_{i,n + 1-i}$ as product of
m disjoint transposition, then  we check
$\gamma(k)=n+1-k=\sigma(k) \forall k\in \{1,\cdot\cdot\cdot,n\}$.
it may be noted  that if $n=2m+1$, then m+1 is a fixed point ie
$\gamma(m+1)=m+1=\sigma(m+1)$, also $sign(\sigma)=(-1)^m$.